# Which extension should I use for notes in vim?

Tags: file, vim, syntax

I'd like to store text in a file and work on it with vim. It would be something very simple, like a .txt on Windows. But I'd like to get basic syntax highlighting. Which file extension and syntax should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the [Vim Outliner](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3515) plugin, which is handy to create short list with sections. The default style has different colours for different levels.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried it and it seems to fit with my description but its colors didn't look good with my current color scheme. So I'll wait a bit to see if this gets other answers.

Comment: @Maxime: just in case you want to change the colours you have to edit the `syntax\vo_base.vim` from vimoutliner. Every colour is defined there.

Comment: Someone actually already did it for the solarized color scheme at http://www.drbunsen.org/writing-in-vim/ I hope he'll send me the file. Thanks for making me search a bit more!

Answer (score 2):

VIM understands [reStructuredText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText), [Markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), and other notations for writing structured text using plain [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (one would have said "ASCII" a while ago).

I find that plain-text *structured* documentation is perfect for my work, besides it being a requirement for sites like [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), or [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/), and the trend in in *doc-comments*.

Comment: I don't clearly understand by what you mean by "VIM understands". Do you mean there is a specific filetype for markup and rest ? Or do you mean something else entirely ? I am interested but puzzled.

Comment: Yes. I mean that VIM knows the file types for RsT and Markup (maybe others I haven't tried), it does the highlighting, and helps with the editing of the structure text.